# How to check if a number is greater than another number in some quantity in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables

How to check if a number is greater than another number in some quantity in JS?

Comment: Subtract one number from the other and see if the result is bigger than 10

Comment: Or add/substract 10 to the respective correct one first, and then compare _those_ values …

Answer (score 1):

Use addition or Subtraction for this,

Example :
let a = 20;
let b = 30;

```
if((a + 10) > b ){
  console.log(' a + 10 is not equal to b');
}

or 
if(a  > ( b - 10) ){
  console.log(' a is not equal to b - 10');
}
```